# Prestashop "Recursive write permissions" error

Tags: permissions, apache2

Trying to install prestashop locally (LAMP), the following error list prevents installation from moving forward.

**Permissions on files and folders**

- Recursive write permissions for www-data user on ~/config/
- Recursive write permissions for www-data user on ~/cache/
- Recursive write permissions for www-data user on ~/log/
- Recursive write permissions for www-data user on ~/img/
- Recursive write permissions for www-data user on ~/mails/
- Recursive write permissions for www-data user on ~/modules/
- Recursive write permissions for www-data user on
  ~/themes/default-bootstrap/lang/
- Recursive write permissions for www-data user on
  ~/themes/default-bootstrap/pdf/lang/
- Recursive write permissions for www-data user on
  ~/themes/default-bootstrap/cache/
- Recursive write permissions for www-data user on ~/translations/
- Recursive write permissions for www-data user on ~/upload/
- Recursive write permissions for www-data user on ~/download/

Also, running the following commands resulted in "Operation not permitted" messages

```
cd /var/www/prestashop

chown -R www-data *

chgrp -R www-data *
```

Comment: I changed my comment to an answer due to a lack of supported formatting for comments.

Comment: Try to run your local server as administrator.

Answer (score 13):

You need to have permission to change ownership. Add sudo to the commands you are executing:

```
sudo cd /var/www/prestashop
sudo chown -R www-data *
sudo chgrp -R www-data *
```

Or just do it all at once, using one command instead of three:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/prestashop
```

Answer (score 3):

favorite
Trying to install prestashop locally (LAMP), the following error list prevents installation from moving forward.

Permissions on files and folders

- Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/config/
- Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/cache/
- Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/log/
- Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/img/
- Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/mails/
- Recursive write permissions for Apache user on ~/modules/

Recursive write permissions for www-data user on ~/download/
Also, running the following commands resulted in "Operation not permitted" messages

I have this type of permissions problem. so i tried this command

```
chmod -R 777 prestashop/
```

It's worked for me, It's may be bad practice to use 777, but i tried to test in local environment it worked.

Comment: ***DO NOT DO THIS!*** This is a DANGEROUS COMMAND!  Using 777 puts your system at risk and is ***NOT SAFE***.

Comment: What are some possible dangers by using 777 in a local setup?

Answer (score 2):

You should not change the prestashop topermissions to 777. It is not safe.

You should only change the ownership of the files/folders. Be logged in as `root` and assuming all your prestashop files/folders are located in `/var/www/public_html/` then cd to `/var/www/` and type:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data public_html/*
```

If you are not logged in as `root`, but you are a sudo user then just add `sudo` to the begining of the command:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data public_html/*
```

**What is chown**

`chown` changes the owner of ALL (see the `/*` at the end?) the files/folders under `public_html` to www-data. The semicolon between the users just specifies the `user`:`user_group`. The `-R` tells the command to be recursive and enter all the subfolders and apply those changes there.

**What is www-data**

Depends on your distribution of linux, it comes by default with `x` defualt users, like `root`. When you install certain applications, the applications create an application specific user. In many distributions, Apache creates a user named `www-data`. So by changing the ownership of the prestashop files/folders to `www-data` you essentially allowing the Apache server to manipulate the files as their permissions allow.

Out of the box, it should work for you without any issues. You might going to have to change permissions to some upload/tmp folders, but only if uploads/upgrades/updates of files/modules fails.

Answer (score -1):

I used this command on SSH and it allows permission for apache user as well as FTP user:

1. login to SSH
2. navigate to your prestashop website folder
3. while you are in it, type this command - replace 'yourftpusername' with your ftp username `chown -R apache:yourftppusername *`

Comment: This isn't a guarantee to fix the issue, esp. if it's running as 'www-data' as Ubuntu packages for Apache and others run as.